# Макрон ЭмманУэль или ЭмманЮэль

Tags: ономастика, имена

Президент Франции Макрон ЭмманУэль или ЭмманЮэль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы ориентировался на Вики, где после [долгого и довольно глубокого обсуждения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9A_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E/17_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F_2017#%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BB%D1%8C_%E2%86%92_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8E%D1%8D%D0%BB%D1%8C) пришли к мнению, что **Эмманюэль**.